# Can Android Work Requests last for a long time

Tags: java, android

In android development, can a Work Request in WorkManager be delayed for a long period of time such as 1year or 1month

Comment: Not an expert here, but guessing: no such requests ever get PERSISTED. This means: whenever the phone restarts, and previous requests will be lost ... and your app, while starting up will create new ones. Thus I doubt that this manager should be used that way. What problem are you trying to solve this way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.